# oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, oracle10g, classnotfoundexception

This is my code for which I am getting error. My `classes12.jar` has been imported as an external jar.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class LoginAction extends HttpServlet {
Connection conn;
Statement stmt;
ResultSet rs;
String query = "SELECT * FROM v_urja_login";
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Hello");
    String u_name = request.getParameter("uname");
    String u_pass = request.getParameter("upass");
    out.println(u_name);
    out.println(u_pass);
    try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","urja","urja");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    }catch(SQLException sex){
        sex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnf) {
        cnf.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at LoginAction.doPost(LoginAction.java:27)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:931)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Where is the code? :)

Comment: And where is the driver located?

Comment: Maroun Maroun I have added the code for you .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
   Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
```

This line causes `ClassNotFoundException`, because you haven't placed `ojdbc14.jar` file in your lib folder of the project. or YOu haven't set the `classpath` of the required jar

Comment: Added that also but not getting the solution.

Comment: @Mavrick Also Add classes12.jar in your lib folder

Comment: @Mavrick do you find them in the reference library...because when you add the jar in lib they will automatically show in reference library check once in that

Answer (score 10):

`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`

Just add the **ojdbc14.jar** to your classpath.

The following are the steps that are given below to add ojdbc14.jar in eclipse:

1) Inside your project

2) Libraries

3) Right click on JRE System Library

4) Build Path

5) Select Configure Build Path

6) Click on Add external JARs...

7) C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib

8) Here you will get ojdbc14.jar

9) select here

10) open

11) ok

save and run the program you will get output.

Answer (score 5):

In Eclipse , rightclick on your application

**Run As -> Run configurations ->** select your server from **type filter text box**

Then in Classpath under **Bootstrap Entries** add your **classes12.jar File** and Click on **Apply**.
Now, run the file...... This worked for me !!

Answer (score 1):

Method 1: Download ojdbc.jar

add ojdbc6.jar to deployment assembly. Right click on project->properties->select deployment assembly->click on 'Add' ->select 'Archives from File System'->browse to the folder where ojdbc6.jar is saved.->add the jar->click finish->Apply/OK.

Method 2:

if you want to add ojdbc.jar to your maven dependencies you follow this link: http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/
 .
 . 
Even if you're using a maven project it is not necessary to add ojdbc to maven dependencies(method 2), method 1 (adding directly to deployment assembly) works just fine.

Comment: Method 1 has saved me. Thanks a lot.:)

Answer (score 0):

try to add ojdbc6.jar or other version through the server lib "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\lib",

Then restart the server in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

1.Right click on your java project.

2.Select "RUN AS".

3.Select "RUN CONFIGURATIOS...".

4.Here select your server at left side of the page and then u would see "CLASS PATH" tab at riht side,just click on it.

5.Here clilck on "USER ENTRIES" and select "ADD EXTERNAL JARS".

6.Select "ojdbc14.jar" file.

7.Click on Apply.

8.Click on Run.

9.Finally Restart your server then it would be execute.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse,

When you use JDBC in your servlet, the driver jar must be placed in the WEB-INF/lib directory of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Not faced the issue ,After added Ojdbc8 dependency in the pom file.

Answer (score -2):

You can add a JAR which having above specified class exist e.g.ojdbc jar which supported by installed java version, also make sure that you have added it into classpath.